# While using silverlight, is there a way to use a button to change the webpage?

Tags: c#, silverlight, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an ASP.MVC application which has a silverlight app inside. I want to change the page when I click one of my buttons. Is there a way to make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the HtmlPage.Navigate method is probably what you're looking for.

You'll need the following using statement:
`using System.Windows.Browser;`

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.mypage.com/newPage.html"));
```

Just stick this guy in the click event of your button and it should do what you want.

Also, if you wish to navigate within your website, you can use a Relative URI, like so:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("newPage.html", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: My VS is complaining that this Navigate method doesnt exist.

Answer (score 0):

What should be done is to use the `using System.Windows.Browser;` statement, and the, in the click method, add the following code:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://yourpagegoeshere.com"));
```

Thanks overhed!

Comment: I was just about to edit my post. :)

It looks like they changed this class a bit since the last time I used it.